Template function called even though requirement evaluates to false
I have been playing with templates.
My goal was to write a concept which requires that all variadic arguments are of the same type.
I did multiple approaches, trying to find the cleanest one. Some approaches were not behaving as I expected so I am here trying to find explanation for it.
I will provide whole code here with some comments:
#include <concepts>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <print>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

template <typename T1, typename... Ts>
constexpr bool same_type_v = (std::is_same_v<T1, Ts> && ...);

template <typename T1, typename... Ts>
concept StdAllSame = (std::is_same_v<T1, Ts> && ...);

template <typename... Ts>
concept CustomAllSame = same_type_v<Ts...>;

// Called on same_type_v being false
// Why?
void a1(CustomAllSame auto... args)
{
    std::println("{}", same_type_v<decltype(args)...>);
    ([&]{ std::println("    {}", typeid(args).name()); }(), ...);
}

// Called on same_type_v being false
// Why?
template <CustomAllSame... T>
void b1(T... args)
{
    std::println("{}", same_type_v<decltype(args)...>);
    ([&]{ std::println("    {}", typeid(args).name()); }(), ...);
}

// This works as intended
template <typename... T>
requires CustomAllSame<T...>
void c1(T... args)
{
    std::println("{}", same_type_v<decltype(args)...>);
    ([&]{ std::println("    {}", typeid(args).name()); }(), ...);
}

// Called on same_type_v being false
// Why?
void a2(StdAllSame auto... args)
{
    std::println("{}", same_type_v<decltype(args)...>);
    ([&]{ std::println("    {}", typeid(args).name()); }(), ...);
}

// Called on same_type_v being false
// Why?
template <StdAllSame... T>
void b2(T... args)
{
    std::println("{}", same_type_v<decltype(args)...>);
    ([&]{ std::println("    {}", typeid(args).name()); }(), ...);
}

// Does not compile at all
// template <typename... T>
// requires StdAllSame<T...>
// void c2(T... args)
// {
//     std::println("{}", same_type_v<decltype(args)...>);
//     ([&]{ std::println("    {}", typeid(args).name()); }(), ...);
// }

int main()
{
    a1(1, 2, 3.0);
    b1(1, 2, 3.0);
    // c1(1, 2, 3.0); -> works properly, does not compile
    a2(1, 2, 3.0);
    b2(1, 2, 3.0);
    // c2(1, 2, 3.0);

    a1(1, 2);
    b1(1, 2);
    c1(1, 2);
    a2(1, 2);
    b2(1, 2);
    // c2(1, 2);
    
}

Code was compiled on Windows 11 with clang version 18.1.2: clang++ --std=c++23 main.cpp
Edit 1: Simplified example
